# Database is locked error in sqlite iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am working on sqlite and inserting value in database but I am getting  Database is locked error 
Here is my code

```
-(void)addmoreDATADetails
{


    if(addStmt == nil) 
    {
        const char *sql = "insert into moreBankroll(MoreName) Values(?)";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [moreName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else
    {

        moreId=sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
    }
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);


    }
```

IF I am adding

```
XYZAppDelegate *appDelegate = (XYZAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  dbPath =[appDelegate getDBPath];
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

this in above function it is saying that no Such table moreBankroll

This code is working fine in another project but not in my project , please help

Comment: That can be any number of things. Another function has probably not released the database.

Comment: What's the content of `dbPath`?

Comment: Db path is /Users/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/29886D95-C7E7-4D8A-9A14-C9BA63549E19/Documents/PokerDatabase.sqlite

Comment: I am having this error when I added foriegn key . but the above table has no reference with foriegn key

Comment: Check your tables now. Is moreBankroll listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database lock error comes only when you are creating some database operation and inside it you start with another database operation.
Try separating out two operations if there are.
Reason for this is that every-time it create a transaction and so you get this error.

Hope, this description helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I will try what you suggest

Answer (score 2):

Your DB is locked because other thread/operation is performing a query to it. Using SQLite in iPhone is very painful the way you do it, maybe you should consider rewriting it with use of FMDB wrapper - it handles all locks by itself and query the data.
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb